# SVN tortoise merging specified files

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have 2 branches. And sometimes I want to merge them one with another. There is issue with this when branches are merging all files in folders are merging too. How can I merge specified files? For example: there are 3 files file1.c, file2.c, file3.c in two different branches, I want to merge branch1 with branch2 excluding file1.c from branch2. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

1. Read [SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.merge.html), note also ["Subtree Merges and Subtree Mergeinfo"](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.stayinsync.subtree) topic in the same source for some not-so-obvious tricks
2. Just **do** partial merge - you can use not only full path to branch-root as source for merges, but *any valid path below it* for performing "subtree merge", even single file

Thus

> I want to merge branch1 with branch2 excluding file1.c from branch2

in correct form will be

> Merge file2 + file3 from branchX to branchY

Comment: such  way only allows me to merge a path or only one file, what if I want to merge two files from two different branches? I should merge them one by one?

Comment: @Doot_Doot - what is "merge two files from two different branches" **for you**? In terms of SVN: you always merge files from two different trees (branches are trees also)

Comment: I mean that I want merge only x,y,z files when merging trees